# Стрелка прокрутки экрана отображается не корректно

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всегда использовал эту комбинацию, но в последнем проекте никак не могу справиться. Блок со стрелкой должен располагаться в левой части экрана (слева от контента), но он располагается под футером (скриншот)
[image: удлиняет страницу]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>


            <div class="all_body">
    <!-- Главное меню -->
<div class="main_menu">

</div>
    <!-- Главное меню конец -->

    <!-- Контент -->
        <div class="content">

<table class="main_table_content">
<tr>
<td width="*">

</td>

<td width="15%" style="border-left: 1px solid black;">

                                <!-- Панель пользователя -->

    <div id="user_panel">

    </div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
        </div>
    <!-- Контент конец -->



<div id="footer">

                                     <!-- POPup -->
    <div id="popupContact">
    <a id="popupContactClose">X</a>
    <h1>Форма для отправки письма</h1>
    <p id="contactArea">

    </p>
    </div>
    <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
                                    <!-- POPup end -->

    <table width="100%" height="550px">
        <td width="35%"> <!-- кнопы футера -->

        </td>
        <td width="1%">

        </td>
        <td width="*"> <!-- баннеры рекламы -->

        </td>
    </table>
</div>
            </div>




<!-- scroll arrow -->
<p id="back-top"><a href="#"><span></span></a></p>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS: (стили стрелки в самом низу)

```
body {
    background: url(../img/back_top.jpg);
}
A img {
   border: none;
}
A {
   color: black; Text-decoration: none;
}
A:visited {
   color: black; Text-decoration: none;
}
A:active {
   color: black; Text-decoration: none;
}
A:hover {
   color: black; Text-decoration: none;
}

div.all_body {
   width: 100%;
   background: url(../img/back.jpg);
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0 auto;
}

div.main_menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(../img/back.jpg);
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.main_table_content #user_panel {
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 101;
    display: block;
}

#user_panel .img_panel {
    width: 150px;
    height: 210px;
    align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 20px;
}

.username_panel {
    font:1.1em Segoe Print,sans-serif;
}

div.content {
    background: url(../img/back.jpg);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
    width: 93em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.main_table_content {
    width: 100%;
}

.main_table_content td {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.main_table_content p {
    margin: 10px;
}

.content_table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.content_table td {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#footer {
    width: 93em;
    height: 555px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#footer .footer_rekl {
  align:center;
  margin-left:25px;
  margin-top:10px;
  border:0;
}


/****************************** scroll-arrow *****************************/
#back-top{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:10px;
    left: -6px;
    z-index: 999;
    border:0;
}

#back-top a{
    width:50px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    font:11px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition:1s;
    -moz-transition:1s;
    transition:1s;
    border:0;
    z-index: 999;
}

/* графическая стрелка */
#back-top span{
    width:50px;
    height:800px;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:7px;
    background: url('../img/up-arrow.png') no-repeat bottom center;
    -webkit-transition:1s;
    -moz-transition:1s;
    transition:1s;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0.4);
    border:0;
    z-index: 999;
}

#back-top span:hover {
   opacity: 1;
   filter: alpha(opacity=1);
   border:0;
}

#back-top a:hover span{background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function (){
        $("#back-top").hide();

        $(window).scroll(function (){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 700){
                $("#back-top").fadeIn();
            } else{
                $("#back-top").fadeOut();
            }
        });

        $("#back-top a").click(function (){
            $("body,html").animate({
                scrollTop:0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Скорректировал, но проблема осталась. Кстати для теста div footer вообще удалил - то же самое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я картинки не выбирал особо, подправите под себя

```js
jQuery(function() {
  $("#Go_Top").hide().removeAttr("href");
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= "250") $("#Go_Top").fadeIn("slow")
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() <= "250") $("#Go_Top").fadeOut("slow")
    else $("#Go_Top").fadeIn("slow")
  });

  $("#Go_Bottom").hide().removeAttr("href");
  if ($(window).scrollTop() <= $(document).height() - "999") $("#Go_Bottom").fadeIn("slow")
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - "999") $("#Go_Bottom").fadeOut("slow")
    else $("#Go_Bottom").fadeIn("slow")
  });

  $("#Go_Top").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, "slow")
  })
  $("#Go_Bottom").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, "slow")
  })
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 4000px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a style='position: fixed; bottom: 60px; right: 1px; cursor:pointer; display:none;' href='#' id='Go_Top'>
  <img src="http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/sphericaicons/128x128/scrollup.png" alt="Наверх" title="Наверх">
</a>
<a style='position: fixed; bottom: 20px; right:0; cursor:pointer; display:none;' href='#' id='Go_Bottom'>
  <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dcr/MKo/dcrMKo4qi.png" alt="Вниз" title="Вниз">
</a>


<div class="Go_bottom"></div>
```

[источник](http://usefulscript.ru/scroll_top_buttom.php)

Comment: Спасибо. Хоть и не ответ, но такой способ вполне меня устроил!

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте `#footer { overflow: hidden; }` или clearfix.

*Потому что у Вас в футере таблица с высотой 550px.*

**Для наглядности** изменила фон `#footer` и кнопки `#back-top` на черный, добавила высоты контенту. **Только для наглядности!**:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function (){
        $("#back-top").hide();

        $(window).scroll(function (){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 700){
                $("#back-top").fadeIn();
            } else{
                $("#back-top").fadeOut();
            }
        });

        $("#back-top a").click(function (){
            $("body,html").animate({
                scrollTop:0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background: url(../img/back_top.jpg);
}
A img {
   border: none;
}
A {
   color: black; Text-decoration: none;
}
A:visited {
   color: black; Text-decoration: none;
}
A:active {
   color: black; Text-decoration: none;
}
A:hover {
   color: black; Text-decoration: none;
}

div.all_body {
   width: 100%;
   background: url(../img/back.jpg);
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0 auto;
}

div.main_menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(../img/back.jpg);
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.main_table_content #user_panel {
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 101;
    display: block;
}

#user_panel .img_panel {
    width: 150px;
    height: 210px;
    align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 20px;
}

.username_panel {
    font:1.1em Segoe Print,sans-serif;
}

div.content {
    background: url(../img/back.jpg);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
    width: 93em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
  
  height: 800px; /* Только для наглядности.  */
}

.main_table_content {
    width: 100%;
}

.main_table_content td {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.main_table_content p {
    margin: 10px;
}

.content_table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.content_table td {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#footer {
    width: 93em;
    height: 555px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    overflow: hidden; /* Добавить */
    background: #333; /* Для наглядности */
}

#footer .footer_rekl {
  align:center;
  margin-left:25px;
  margin-top:10px;
  border:0;
}


/****************************** scroll-arrow *****************************/
#back-top{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:10px;
    left: -6px;
    z-index: 999;
    border:0;
  
      background: aqua; /* Для наглядности */
}

#back-top a{
    width:50px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    font:11px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition:1s;
    -moz-transition:1s;
    transition:1s;
    border:0;
    z-index: 999;
}

/* графическая стрелка */
#back-top span{
    width:50px;
    height:800px;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:7px;
    background: url('../img/up-arrow.png') no-repeat bottom center;
    -webkit-transition:1s;
    -moz-transition:1s;
    transition:1s;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0.4);
    border:0;
    z-index: 999;
}

#back-top span:hover {
   opacity: 1;
   filter: alpha(opacity=1);
   border:0;
}

#back-top a:hover span{background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>пример</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="all_body">
    <!-- Главное меню -->
   <div class="main_menu"> </div>
    <!-- Главное меню конец -->

    <!-- Контент -->
    <div class="content">

      <table class="main_table_content">
        <tr>
         <td width="*"> </td>

         <td width="15%" style="border-left: 1px solid black;">

                                <!-- Панель пользователя -->

            <div id="user_panel">  </div>

         </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
    <!-- Контент конец -->



<div id="footer">

                                     <!-- POPup -->
    <div id="popupContact">
      <a id="popupContactClose">X</a>
      <h1>Форма для отправки письма</h1>
      <p id="contactArea">

      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
                                    <!-- POPup end -->

        <table width="100%" height="550px">
            <td width="35%"> <!-- кнопы футера -->

            </td>
            <td width="1%">

            </td>
            <td width="*"> <!-- баннеры рекламы -->

            </td>
        </table>
    </div>
 </div>




<!-- scroll arrow -->
<p id="back-top"><a href="#"><span></span></a></p>


</body>
</html>
```

*И исправьте везде `padding: 0 auto;` **на** `padding: 0;`

Comment: спасибо, но у меня так и не заработало, хотя на Вашем исправленном примере  все ок. Видимо у меня еще где-то конфликт (я не весь код выкладывал)